# Free memory and pending tasks of called function after execution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I am using MATLAB GUI where a callback function calls so many other complex functions. If that callback function is called once than after its execution, all further processing get delayed. If that callback function is never called than processing speed is normal. What can be the issue?

If it's memory issue, I want to clear all memory and pending tasks for complex callback function after its execution so that the further processing is not delayed. Any help?

I tried `clear function` and `clear variables` at the end of a complex callback function but no improvement.

Comment: Why is this `very important`?

Comment: i have been working for month but cant reach to a solution. and its very important for me... kindly help me if u know the answer

Comment: Well, it's hard to say what the issue is without any code. If your callback is calling several other functions, try to decompose it (e.g. by commenting parts of the code) to track down the source of the problem.

Comment: is there any way to prioritize callbacks in matlab? or something which can stop execution of running callback if some specific callback is called?

Comment: this is very alarming. i have actually used imshow to display images which when called in loop occupies virtual memory.